# Can't upload my own CV to SO jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When applying for a job on Stack Overflow jobs I get:

> If you don't upload a resume, we'll attach a PDF version of your Developer Story for you.

But there is no option to upload my resume. How can I do this?

[image]

It turns out my corporate firewall blocks Dropbox.

Comment: Do you see a drop zone allowing you to drag/drop or click to upload a file? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTt9P.png

Comment: If not can you check if there are any script errors in the console?

Comment: As seen in the attached photo, I'm blocked from using dropbox. I can't work around the block, so no worries.

Comment: OK, thanks, investigating now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made the code here a little more defensive; it now checks for the presence of the `Dropbox` global before testing for Dropbox support. That's fixed and pushed to prod - let us know if you continue to see problems.

Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Thanks Dean, it works now :)